# Selecting the prompt with Capybara

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, select, capybara

I have a select dropdown:

```
<%= f.select :image_size_id, options_for_select(@image_sizes.collect{ |i| [i.dimension, { id: i.dimension} ]}), { prompt: "Please select a Print Size" }, id: 'image_size_select' %>
```

Which returns this in HTML:

```
<select id="image_size_select" name="cart_item[image_size_id]">
  <option value="">Please select a Print Size</option>
  <option id="10x8" value="13">10x8 £14.0</option>
  <option id="A4" value="14">A4 £33.0</option>
  <option id="A3" value="15">A3 £36.0</option>
  <option id="A2" value="16">A2 £47.0</option>
</select>
```

At the moment to select an option within my tests I can use for example:

```
find('#image_size_select').find("option[id='A2']").select_option
find('#image_size_select').find("option[value='14']").select_option
```

What I want to do though is select the prompt so that I can test my validation, can I set an id of the prompt or select by text ? I have tried:

```
find('#image_size_select').find("option[text='find('#image_size_select').find("option[id='A2']").select_option']").select_option
```

But that doesn't work, nor does:

```
find('#image_size_select').find(:xpath, 'option[1]').select_option
```

Comment: Have you tried with `find("option[value='13']").click`?

Comment: @faberskyThat's not the one i want to click though.... I want to select the prompt

Comment: Can you try `page.select "", from: 'image_size_select'` ?

Comment: @eugen, thanks v much, that has worked :-), mark it as the answer (with an explanation as to why that works?) and ill mark it as the asnwer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capybaras `#select` chooses the option by the text, not value, of the option element.  When passed with a :from option it is implemented as `find(:select, '<select id, name, or associated label text (the :from option)>').find(:option, '<text of option element>').select_option`  which means the correct call to select the first option in the specified select is

```
page.select "Please select a Print Size", from: 'image_size_select'
```

to select the next option

```
page.select "10x8 £14.0", from: 'image_size_select'
```

Due to Capybaras default partial string matching

```
page.select "10x8", from: 'image_size_select'
```

would also select the 10x8 option as long as "10x8" is a partial match to only one of the options in the select

Answer (score 1):

`page.select "", from: 'image_size_select'` should work. `select` allows you to select options from a select drop-down based on value (which in this case it's actually an empty string) and the select drop-down can be found in the page via name, id or label.

The documentation of the method is at http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FActions%3Aselect

Comment: Thanks again, any ideas on how to get the first option with '' ?

Comment: How about `find('#image_size_select').find("option[value='']")` then?

Comment: @eugen Your description of what #select matches against is not correct, please see my answer

Comment: @Richlewis, Tom is correct - you should approve his answer.